# How to vectorize the output created by a while loop in R?

Tags: r, loops, while-loop, vectorization

I would like to get the results from a while loop as a vector. My code looks like this and nld is just some numeric data and lk represents yearly rate of a country:

```
 i<-1
  while (i<=length(nld)) {
    lk<-((nld[i+1]-nld[i])/nld[i])*100
    i <- i+1
    print(lk)   }
```

But the output looks like this:

```
> [1] 2.34391
[1] 4.421947
[1] 0.6444809
[1] 11.29308
[1] 4.282817
[1] 1.773046
[1] 5.443044
[1] 6.332272
[1] 9.207917
[1] 6.173719
[1] 5.449088
[1] 3.977678
[1] 7.697896
[1] 6.313985
[1] 1.449447
[1] 5.149968
[1] 1.840442
[1] 2.628424
[1] 2.269874
[1] 4.195588
[1] -2.868499
[1] -2.764851
[1] 0.216549
[1] 1.907869
[1] -2.13202
[1] 4.637701
[1] 1.051423
[1] 3.946669
[1] 4.332345
[1] 6.260946
[1] 3.113528
[1] 1.537622
[1] 3.075729
[1] 2.925915
[1] 5.146445
[1] 6.129935
[1] 5.185049
[1] 3.45909
[1] 7.835161
[1] 9.649116
[1] 1.311721
[1] 0.3325002
```

... etc.

and i can't get and plot these results from this loop. I would be appreciated if someone could enlighthen me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Define `nld` in the question so we can run the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i <- 1
result <- c()
while (i<=length(nld)) {
    lk<-((nld[i+1]-nld[i])/nld[i])*100
    i <- i+1
    result <- c(result, lk)   } # this collects `lk`  in the vector `result`.
```

But what you are doing is very C-ish (or C++-ish).
Whenever in R or Python you see indexes and index incrementation,
in 99% of the cases there is a better expression in R or Python.

E.g. in this case, you are actually going through `nld` using a while loop - that is not good.

In R you would use `Map()` - which can iterate in parallel through vectors/lists.

```
nld <- 1:10
result <- Map(f=function(x, y) (x - y)/y * 100,
              nld[2:length(nld)],
              nld)
```

But there is a mistake in your original code.
You loop from `i=1` to `i=length(nld)` but requires `nld[i+1]`.
The `i+1` would in the last case demand sth not existing.
so it should be `while (i < length(nld)) { ...`
and

```
result <- Map(f=function(x, y) (x - y)/y * 100,
              nld[2:length(nld)],
              nld[1:(length(nld)-1)])
```

Or even more R-ish: use vectorization:

```
f <- function(x, y) (x-y)/y*100
> f(nld[2:length(nld)], nld[1:(length(nld)-1)])
## [1] 100.00000  50.00000  33.33333  25.00000  20.00000  16.66667  14.28571
## [8]  12.50000  11.11111
```

Or:

```
f <- function(vec) {
  vec1 <- vec[2:length(vec)]
  vec2 <- vec[1:(length(vec)-1)]
  (vec1 - vec2)/vec1 * 100 # this uses vectorization!
}

f(nld)
```